# What is the best solution for this UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-update, sqlanywhere

what is the best way for this SQL?

A)

```
update tableName set 
FieldA = (if FieldA = 1301 then null else FieldA endif), 
FieldB = (if FieldB = 1301 then null else FieldB endif)
where Id = 707;
```

or

B)

```
update tableName set FieldA = null where Id= 707 and FieldA = 1301;
update tableName set FieldB = null where Id= 707 and FieldB = 1301;
```

In Model "A" I only have one SQL that works and solves the problem, and model "B" I have two SQL's, that do the same thing as the "A" model but more readable.

What would be the most appropriate model to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that A solution is better because:

1 less logical IO - better performance

2 less program code, less errors

3 ease to support and maintain

4 this update is pretty readable

Comment: I wonder whther the first option A) could not trigger update triggers even when FieldA<>1301; or even an update IO. I mean, will the engine know that `update set FieldA=FieldA` would be a NOP?

Comment: I think that server performs IO operations in this case, but it is a fast inplace update.